# Want to display the top 3 teams

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, display

I have a spreadsheet of football fixtures of 3 seperate leagues. Premier league names are in D1 to D10 and the amount of goals they have scored are in F1 to F10. IT's the same for the other two leagues. M1 to M10 and V1 to V10 has the names and O1 to O10 and X1 to X10 have the goals scored. I want to look up F1 to F10, O1 to O10 and X1 to X10 and display the names of the top 3 teams of all the leagues in seperate cells below say B20 D20 F20. If there are any duplicates it'd be great if they could be displayed in cells below B21 D21 F21.

I'd really appreciate some help thanks.

Comment: So basically if Man U (D1) Has 55 goals (F1) which is the most of all the leagues(F1:F10, O1:O10, X1:X10), Display Man U(D1) in B20. Same for second highest amount and third. Would be great if I could highlight the Team name cell too

Comment: Read about LARGE() and OFFSET(). You can use LARGE() to find the three highest number of goals, and OFFSET() those numbers to list the teams.

Comment: Thanks alot mate LARGE function worked great. Went with INDEX/MATCH instead of OFFSET but got the job done so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I should have given this more thought.  LARGE() works to find the highest scores, but you need to use MATCH() and INDEX() to list the team names.  Sorry if I sent you on a snipe hunt.

Here's an example that lists the teams with the highest number of goals and the goals scored:

[image]

(Side note: Is there REALLY a soccer team representing Nottingham Forest? Is there a Sheriff nearby?)

The formula `LARGE(range,1)` returns the largest number in the range and `LARGE(range,2)` returns the second largest, etc.

In this example, the formula in E14 (just below "Top Scorers") is:

```
=LARGE(E$2:E$11,ROW()-13)
```

I got a little fancy here and used the current row -13 as the index. Since the formula is in row 14, the index evaluates to 1,2,3 etc., as it is filled down.  Otherwise you'd have to edit the formula in every row to change the index.

The formula in D14 is:

```
=INDEX(D2:D11,(MATCH(E14,E$2:E$11,0)))
```

The MATCH() function returns the position of the score in Column E in the list of goals scored, and the INDEX() function returns the name of the team in that position of the list of team names.

This last formula won't work correctly if there are duplicate scores, because MATCH() always returns the first match that it finds.

But, I'll come back with an edit to handle that problem.